# use alias only once in bashrc

Tags: bash

I wrote an alias in my .bashrc file that open a txt file every time I start bash shell.
The problem is that I would like to open such a file only once, that is the first time I open the shell.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the motivation for this question.  If you want commands only to be executed on first login, put them in `.login` or `.bash_login`, which is executed by sh-like shells when they start only if they are login shells, unlike .bashrc which is executed by both login and non-login bash shells.

Comment: I'v tried to edit these files, but it didn't work. I have just put the command 'gvim path/file.txt' and then when I started the bash session nothing happend.

Comment: Concur that you should probably try to solve that problem instead, or as well. Post a separate question!

Comment: Are you using Mac OS?  Terminal.app has the weird behaviour of invoking a login shell each time it starts.  You can test whether you are in such a shell by looking at the contents of TERM_PROGRAM.  From MacOS, the open command allows you to avoid opening the same file multiple times.

Comment: I'm not using Mac OS but Linux Scientific. Anyway, it seems I found out the problem (looking on internet). I'm working on a X session, meaning I'm not running a login bash shell but a simple shell which doesn't read .login or .bash_login but directly .bashrc. But anyway, thank you both for your useful comments. I'll try to change strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to this problem is to have a session lock of some kind. You could create a file /tmp/secret with the pid and/or tty of the process which is editing the other file, and remove the lock file when done.  Now, your other sessions should be set up to not create this file if it already exists.

Proper locking is a complex topic, but for the simple cases, this might be good enough. If not, google for "mutual exclusion". Do note that there may be security implications if you get it wrong.

Why are you using an alias for this? Sounds like the code should be directly in your .bashrc, not in an alias definition.

So if, say, what you have now in your `.bashrc` is something like

```
alias start_editing_my_project_work_hour_report='emacs ~/prj.txt &̈́'
start_editing_my_project_work_hour_report
unalias start_editing_my_project_work_hour_report
```

... then with the locking, and without the alias, you might end up with something like

```
# Obtain my UID on this host, and construct directory name and lock file name
uid=$(id -u)
dir=/tmp/prj-$uid
lock=$dir/pid.lock

# The loop will execute at most twice,
# but we don't know yet whether once is enough
while true; do
  if mkdir -p "$dir"; then
     # Yay, we have the lock!
     ( echo $$ >"$lock" ; emacs ~/prj.txt; rm -f "$lock" ) &
     break

  else
     other=$(cat "$lock")

     # If the process which created the UID is still live, do nothing
     if kill -0 $other; then
       break
     else
       echo "removing stale lock file dir (dead PID $other) and retrying" >&2
       rm -rf "$dir"
       continue
     fi
  fi
done
```